# Open application from website

Tags: javascript, selenium

I launched a web application/website from a jar application using selenium webdriver. The web application is running in fullscreen. 
Can I bring the jar application to front of web application.. i.e. I want to trigger an event from web application such that it shows up the jar. 
 The event can be click of button or sendkeys etc.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. You can't really communicate with something out of the browser, from within a web page.

Comment: No that's not possible. However, what you can do is set the jar application to focus form within itself once the web application is launched.

Comment: What are you try

Comment: It might be possible by registering your own URI scheme in OS and then open links that lead to `customSchemeProtocol://...` and deal with that inside your java app.